# Migrating SQL server to new hardware - restore msdb vs scripts job?

Tags: sql-server, migration, sql-server-2019

I am planning for sql server 2019 migration to new hardware.

For the server level logins, roles I can either restore the master db or script these out.

Similarly, for sql agent jobs I can either restore the msdb db or script these out.

When migrating SQL server (same version) to new hardware, are both options feasible? (that is restore of msdb vs scripting)?

Answer (score 1):

> When migrating SQL server (same version) to new hardware, what are both options feasible? (that is restore of master/msdb or scripting)?

As already stated on one of your questions, if the version and CU level remain "exactly" same there would be no problem in restoring system databases. I would prefer restore than scripting out.

Answer (score 0):

DBA TOOLS!

https://dbatools.io/commands/ (specifically those under Migration)